# Tooltip background (with JavaFX CSS)

Tags: javafx, tooltip

Simple question, but I just can't find the answer anywhere (I suppose I don't know what exactly to look for...). How can I prevent my tooltips from displaying an ugly square with the scene's background image as background like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZcTP.jpg)?!

This is my CSS, I believe some of the options such as the buttons are affecting the tooltip... just as they affect my Datepickers in another part of the code. How do I manage them not to have this collateral effect? Will simply defining a CSS for specific objects such as the DatePicker or the Tooltip do the trick?

I'm using JDK 8u11, MAC OS Mavericks.

```
.root {
     -fx-background-image: url("media/background.jpg");
}

.button {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),
        linear-gradient(#020b02, #3a3a3a),
        linear-gradient(#9d9e9d 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #242424 100%),
        linear-gradient(#8a8a8a 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #262626 100%),
        linear-gradient(#777777 0%, #606060 50%, #505250 51%, #2a2b2a 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5,6;
    -fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4,3;
    -fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.2) , 1, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(#757575 0%, #373837 25%, #232723 75%, #686868 100%),
        linear-gradient(#3a3a3a, #020b02),
        linear-gradient(#242424 0%, #343534 20%, #6b6a6b 80%, #9d9e9d 100%),
        linear-gradient(#262626 0%, #343534 20%, #6b6a6b 80%, #8a8a8a 100%),
        linear-gradient(#2a2b2a 0%, #505250 50%, #606060 51%, #777777 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5,6;
    -fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4,3;
    -fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.2) , 1, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
    -fx-cursor:hand;
}

.text-area *.text {
    -fx-text-alignment: justify;
}

.text-area {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.text-area .scroll-pane .viewport{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}


.text-area .scroll-pane .content{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.radio-button{
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
   -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
   -fx-fill: #818181;
   -fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 6, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );
}
```

Comment: This is strange. Maybe some CSS that you use to style other nodes is also accidentally applied to the tooltip?

Comment: Yes I think so... should I post my CSS file? It's pretty short...

Comment: I just edited and posted the CSS, please have a look

Comment: Just out of curiosity... is there a way to remove all styles before adding one... as to make sure there won't be any interference?

Comment: I am not aware of any such thing. When you set style programatically using `node.setStyle("-fx-fill: red;")`, then the subsequent `setStyle` will override the previous value, but does not clear the style set by an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.root` style class is added to the root node of all scenes. Since `Tooltip` has its own scene, tooltip's root node has the `.root` class as well, so the background image is applied to it as well, as per your CSS. The solution is to add a distinct style class to your main scene's root

```
scene.getRoot().getStyleClass().add("main-root");
```

and specify the background image for this distinct style class

```
.main-root {
    -fx-background-image: url("media/background.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is the standard styling for a Tooltip as per the Java 8 modena.css stylesheet.

```
.tooltip {
    -fx-background: rgba(30,30,30);
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: rgba(30,30,30,0.8);
    -fx-background-radius: 6px;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.667em 0.75em 0.667em 0.75em; /* 10px */
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.5) , 10, 0.0 , 0 , 3 );
    -fx-font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

You can modify it how you wish.  Info on doing so is in the Oracle [CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) and [CSS tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

Comment: I added this code to my CSS... no effect on the Tooltip which seems to retain the scene's background and the the main button format.

Comment: Place an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question that somebody could run but contains *only* the code necessary to replicate your issue.  Also add full environment information to your question (java runtime version and OS).