# JavaFX combobox, getting white background after listview

Tags: combobox, javafx

I m getting a white background in my ComboBox in javaFx

[Screenshot of combobox I m getting](http://postimg.org/image/w9v4eds3r/)

I simply used this

```
ComboBox mode = new ComboBox();
mode.getItems().addAll("Cash", "Cheque", "Account Transfer");
```

Please tell me how to resolve this..

Comment: Do you want a different color than white as background color, or do you want to have at least one entry shown from beginning?

Comment: I want a normal transparent background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25437004/3956070), when the combo is shown a `PopupControl` that extends `PopupWindow' is shown. It has its own scene and styling.

My guess is you have some styling applied to the CSS rule `.root.popup`, something like this:

```
.root.popup {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Try to remove that sytling or change it to:

```
.root.popup {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

and check if the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks!, I applied .root in my css
.root {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-color: #00aeef;
}